# Which one is more correct, "near impossible" or "nearly impossible"?

Tags: phrase-usage, indian-english

Usually, I write *This task is **nearly impossible***, but I read the following line in a [blog](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/tech/mobiles/6-reasons-to-avoid-cheap-smartphones-like-Docoss-X1/articleshow/52050950.cms):

> Even though prices have been dipping, it's ***near impossible*** to manufacture a smartphone at such a low price.

Is it correct? I also want to know whether *nearly impossible* is more used in Indian English.

Answer (score 3):

Both are fine; they are both adverbs, though 'near' is as mentioned above also an adjective and a verb.  It's entirely up to the writer; English is a rich language.  The '-ly' form may place a little more emphasis on the verb, being a conventional adverbial form - the reader's attention is subliminally directed to the verb.[phew, can't quite do it].  'Near' slightly suggests, in contrast, a quality  belonging to whatever is being so described. [wooah, that's not on, effectively]

Answer (score 1):

According to Merriam Webster Dictionary one of the meanings of *near* as an adverb is "almost or nearly" as in "The plant was near dead when I got it." 
You can find it [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/near).

Both are true but according to corpus information "near impossible" is less frequent than "nearly impossible". So it is better to use "nearly impossible".

Answer (score 0):

"Nearly" is an adverb, which means "almost". "Near"  can be an adjective, verb, or adverb:

> I am nearly finished with the assignment. (adverb)
>
> He lives near the school. (preposition)
>
> As we neared the railway station, we could hear the sounds of  trains
>   . (verb)
>
> Their house is  the near side of the lake. (adjective)

In the example sentence, it's "almost impossible" so to be grammatically correct, "nearly" should be used; although "near impossible" [could also be found](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=near+impossible&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=2&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnear%20impossible%3B%2Cc0) which is, strictly speaking, contrary to the grammar books I know of.

Comment: The 'near' in your second example ('near the school') is a preposition rather than an adverb, no?